# Running time analysis of Savitch's algorithm

Tags: complexity-theory, algorithm-analysis, runtime-analysis, space-complexity, average-case

Savitch provided an algorithm which places NL in L^2 and hence the runtime of the algorithm is bound by $2^{O(\log^2n)}$. The runtime of the algorithm is not in P as NL is not known to be in SC.

Is there a runtime analysis of the algorithm anywhere which provides worst and average case behavior of the time complexity?